# Horizontal shift in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

I have changed the Section format for my Appendices using

```
\renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}
```

The problem is that a horizontal shift occurs in the table of content. I have of course found related subjects, and `\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{7em}` turns out to be a solution. However, it affects all sections (body + appendices), which is not wanted.

So, is there a way to use `\setlength` only for the appendices? Or is there another command which can be useful to solve my problem?

Here is an MWE of my document. The result in the body of the document is as desired, but the TOC is not.

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}

\clearpage
\appendix
\renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}  

\section{First annex}
\section{Last annex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: `\cftsecnumwidth` isn't a standard command so presumably it is defined in some package you have not mentioned

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use package `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\appendix{%
  \clearpage
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\protect\cftsecnumwidth}{7em}}%
  \renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}%
}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}

\appendix
\section{First annex}
\section{Last annex}

\end{document}
```

[image]